How to stop ghosting while multiplexing LED matrix?
I tried to make a 4*4 LED matrix and controlling it with an Arduino. With certain LED patterns ghosting occurs. On each row, the LED anodes are connected together and each row goes (from top to bottom) to output pins A, B, C, D of my shift register (SN74HC595N). On each column the LED cathodes are connected together and the columns are connected to the collectors of NPN transistors which are controlled (from left to right) by shift register output pins E, F, G, H. In summary, the first 4 bits control which row is on and the next 4 bits control which column is on. Each transistor has an emitter resistor of 1 kΩ and a base resistor of 10 kΩ. Pin 2 of the Arduino drives Pin 11 of the shift register (SRCLK), Pin 3 drives pin 12 (RCLK), and pin 4 drives pin 14 (SER). I have rechecked the code and wiring multiple times and an LED still glows faintly (ghosts) as in the diagram:
....
....
*..#
#...

where . is an unlit LED, * is a ghosting LED, and # is a fully-on LED.
When I add delay(100); statements at the end of the loop() function, the ghosting LED blinks very faintly and for a very short amount of time just as the display transitions from displaying the LED on the bottom row to the LED on the row above.
Here is the code:
// *** THIS IMAGE IS PROBLEMATIC ***
short display = 0b0000000000011000; // contents of display

// which pixel are we displaying now?
byte index = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT); // SRCLK
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); // RCLK
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT); // SER

  clear();
}

void iterateDisplay() {
  clear();
    
  unsigned short bit = (display >> index) & 1;
  if (bit) {
    byte x = 3 - (index % 4);
    byte y = 3 - (index / 4);
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
      write((x == i) ? HIGH : LOW);
    }
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
      write((y == i) ? HIGH : LOW);
    }
  }

  // update RCLK register
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);

  index++;
  if (index > 15) index = 0;
}

void loop() {  
  iterateDisplay();
  delay(100);
}

void clear() {
  // deactivate all rows and columns
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    write(LOW);
  }
}

void write(byte value) {
  // 4 is the serial in of the shift register
  digitalWrite(4, value);

  // pulse srclk
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
}


PS: I am using the Electronics StackExchange and not the Arduino one because I think the issue is independent of which uC I use. Please correct me if I am wrong. Also I am only getting started in digital electronics so please forgive me for any beginner's mistakes :)
Edit: removed irrelevant code and added more comments

I think adding a schematics (and precise part numbers of the electronics components) might help identifying the issue, specially if you think it's on the electronics side and not in the code

You are multiplexing lighting individual LEDs for a maximum duty cycle of 1/16. Consider an 8x8 matrix: lighting all "active" LEDs of e.g. a single column simultaneously allows a duty cycle of almost 1/8. Using row resistors instead of emitter resistors.

@Burglups  this looks like minimal example code, there's no way to know that there are actually spare pins without asking.  SPI would be another option (instead of bit-bang) if those pins aren't busy on another task.

It sounds like the beginner assumption of transistors being able to turn on and off as instantly as diģital IO pins.
Generally a working sequence would be to turn off the LEDs blank first with the shift register so they turn off immediately, then turn off the transistor, wait a few microseconds for the transistor to stop conducting.
That can also be done transistor first or simultaneously.
Then turn on the transistor and LEDs in some order again, but the point is, you cannot directly change the pattern from one row/column to another as the GPIO pins and 595 expander pins are much faster to trasition than what the slower transistors are capable of.
So solve it by outputing an all off pattern for long enough when moving on from one transistor to next.

If not associated with the dynamics (as suggested above) then I suspect sneak paths.

("turn off the LEDs blank" turn off/blank the LEDs? (turn off the LEDs bank?))

You should also pulse rclk after clear(), and possibly add a short delay in there too.

+1 for the pulse, the delay is already there because of the slow digitalWrite() and other runtime overhead.

To expand on Justme's advice to turn off one transistor before turning on a different one:

Disable the outputs before changing the transistor turned on.
(Too bad the 595's combination of rising edge RCLK & active low OE seems to need an external inverter or separate outputs.)
Shift out the new pattern while the transistor(s?) turn off.
(This would be "simultaneous" if all transistors turn off when outputs are disabled.)
Register and enable when turn-off will be finished before turn-on.

